# Hide Views if Recyclerview is Empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with other widgets in this type of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.joey.joseph.aapnidukan.activities.CheckOutActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backIV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_image"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckOut"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nonEmptyState"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <in.joey.joseph.aapnidukan.utils.EmptyRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkOutRV"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cartTotalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkOutRV"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total: "
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="&#8377;"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPriceTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="8999"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/billingBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Proceed to Billing and Address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyState"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Items to Cart Before CheckOut"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

I have created a custom `RecyclerView` to handle empty states but it works fine for only the `RecyclerView`. The other views like the button are still visible when the list is empty. I have tried to hide it in my custom `RecyclerView` class like this:

```
private void checkNotEmpty(){
    if (nonEmptyView != null && getAdapter() != null){
        boolean nonEmptyViewVisible = getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0;
        nonEmptyView.setVisibility(nonEmptyViewVisible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        setVisibility(nonEmptyViewVisible ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here's the full class code for the `RecyclerView`:

```
public class EmptyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

private View emptyView, nonEmptyView;

public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EmptyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private final AdapterDataObserver dataObserver = new AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        checkEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        checkEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        checkEmpty();
    }
};

private void checkEmpty() {
    if (emptyView != null && getAdapter() != null){
        boolean emptyViewVisible = getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0;
        emptyView.setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void checkNotEmpty(){
    if (nonEmptyView != null && getAdapter() != null){
        boolean nonEmptyViewVisible = getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0;
        nonEmptyView.setVisibility(nonEmptyViewVisible ? VISIBLE : GONE);
        setVisibility(nonEmptyViewVisible ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void setButtonVisibility(Button button){ // to toggle the button visibility
    if (getAdapter().getItemCount() > 0){
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        button.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    Adapter oldAdapter = getAdapter();
    if (oldAdapter != null){
        oldAdapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(dataObserver);
    }
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (adapter != null){
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(dataObserver);
    }

    checkEmpty();
}

public void setEmptyView(View view){
    this.emptyView = view;
    checkEmpty();
}

public void setNonEmptyView(View view2){
    this.nonEmptyView = view2;
    checkNotEmpty();
}

}
```

And in my activity, I have tried this:

```
    init();
    checkOutRV.setEmptyView(emptyState);
    checkOutRV.setNonEmptyView(nonEmptyState);

    private void init() {
    nonEmptyState = findViewById(R.id.nonEmptyState);
    emptyState = findViewById(R.id.emptyState);
    checkOutRV = findViewById(R.id.checkOutRV);

    checkOutRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    checkOutRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

The list has no data right now as I have not made my API call yet, but still, the emptyStateTextView and the buttons are still visible. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default keep your layout `INVISIBLE` and show a layout that shows that the `Recyclerview` has no data or something, and then when you make your API calls and receive the data then hide the layout which show that the recyclerview in empty and set your data layout view to `VISIBLE` which you want to show.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You need to register Data observer to listen to data changes from sync adapter.

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(myObserver);
```

`RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` are a result of which notify methods you call. So for instance if you call `notifyItemInserted()` after you add an item to your adapter then `onItemRangeInserted()` will get called

A more detailed example

```
protected void setupRecyclerView() {
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mItemList);
    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            checkAdapterIsEmpty();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    checkAdapterIsEmpty();
}
```

Also don't forget to unregister the observer.

Comment: That's what the custom class does by checking if the adapter size is 0 or > 0

Comment: I have also tried adapter.getItemCount and then toggle views visibility but that doe4sn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you registered your `AdapterDataObserver` like this : `mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(myObserver); `
also you need to unregister it.

Comment: I already have a data observer in my emptyrecyclerview class. WHat's the difference here and I'm assuming I should check adapter item count in your checkAdapterIsEmpty method? Please explain, might be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

In the checkNonEmpty() method you have called **getAdapter()** which returns null as you have not used setAdapter() on recycler view .

Create an adapter for your recycler view and initialise it with an empty list , then setAdapter() on your view.

Then you can use these statements

```
  checkOutRV.setEmptyView(emptyState);
  checkOutRV.setNonEmptyView(nonEmptyState);
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        >

        ...

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/nonEmptyState"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Existing layout like recyclerview, button -->
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/emptyStateLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emptyState"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Add Items to Cart Before CheckOut"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just set **emptyStateLayout** `VISIBLE` when `RecyclerView` is empty, otherwise `GONE`

Comment: That's not related to the problem. I want to show/hide the button depending on if the recyclerview has data or not.

Comment: Your layout is not correct. There should be only one root layout. And you want to show/hide the `button` or `clearstate` `TextView`?

Comment: Not working. The layout has nothing to do with this problem